# Any way to set profile pic using FB  for Android App (1.8.1 on ICS)?

Tags: facebook

I've resorted to the FB Mobile site which isn't a bad compromise really, but I was going a little crazy trying to find the option within the FB App, just wondering if it exists?

Comment: The Facebook app has been completely re-written and is now on version 2.2.1. Is this question still relevant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do so in the mobile app.

I am using Facebook App Version 1.8.1 on a Motorola Droid 3.

The process I did to set a picture as my profile picture was as follows:

1. Started Facebook
2. At the top left there was an icon with 3 horizontal dashes that brings up the different sections of Facebook, I browsed down to the "Photos" section under Apps.
3. I selected a photo out of my list of Photos (It would not let me select the option on anyone else's photo; so I assume it must be one uploaded into your account).
4. I used my phone's physical Menu button to open the Facebook menu.
5. I hit the "More" arrow button to list more options in the menu. One of these extra options was to "Make profile picture"

It  may be slightly different on your device; however it is possible to do this in the latest Facebook version on the desired photo.

Comment: Hmmm thanks for trying :) - I don't appear to have the "Make profile picture" option in #5. 

I'm running it on ICS however which I suppose could be the difference although it is still 1.8.1.

Comment: That is odd, works on gingerbread and honeycomb...

Answer (score -1):

For honeycomb you could go into pics on your phone and hit set as and Facebook profile was an option. Now that my phone has ICS, it only gives me the option of setting as wallpaper or contact photo. With ICS you can only set profile pic from pics already on Facebook, but not upload from pics on phone. It's very annoying.

Comment: Once you have added a photo to Facebook it's very easy. Just open the photo (in Facebook), tap the "More" menu, and choose "Set as profile photo".